# Generating Files with JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to generate a file to download. With JavaScript I call a PHP file to process my request and send back the result in a way it should be possible to download it. But instead of making it available for download it simply display the code.

**PHP**

```
function export()
{
    // Get a database object.   
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select fields to get.
    $fields = array(
        $db->quoteName('params')
    );

    // Conditions for which records should be get.
    $conditions = array(
        $db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $db->quote('plugin_name'), 
        $db->quoteName('folder') . ' = ' . $db->quote('system')
    );

    // Set the query and load the result.
    $query->select($fields)->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions'))->where($conditions);
    $db->setQuery($query);   
    $results = $db->loadResult(); 

    // Namming the filename that will be generated.
    $name      = 'file_name';
    $date      = date("Ymd");
    $json_name = $name."-".$date;

    // Clean the output buffer.
    ob_clean();

    echo $results;
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$json_name.'.json');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function downloadFile() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('task', 'export');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "my_php_file");
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

HTML file

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success" type="button" onclick="downloadFile()"></button>
```

UPDATE MY CODE

Comment: Also I see ob_clean() I assume in your missing code you have ob_start() somewhere?

Comment: *"it simply display the code"* - Is your file `.php` extension?

Comment: yes you are missing ob_start() "The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE flag. Otherwise ob_clean() will not work. "  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php  see my example below

Comment: What "code" is being displayed? Can you make an example using static content instead of the DB queries?

Comment: @mrjamesmyers Yes you're right. but even correcting it continues to give the same result

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara It's the query result, and it´s correct `"admin_login_image_tiles":0,"admin_login_background_image":"","admin_login_background_image_property":"cover".......` that's what it should put in a file

Comment: Yeah my guess would be that it is not interpreting the file as PHP, as @Fred-ii- asked has the file got PHP extension, is PHP definitely installed on the server? If you create a new php file phpinfo.php with phpinfo(); do you get any results?

Comment: Are you using PHP file includes with a .inc extension?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript `uploadComplete` function, what does it do? And you are aware that you will not get presented with a download dialog for a request that was made in the _background_ using AJAX, right?

Comment: @CBroe I think that is the problem. I was reading right now about it. How can i do it? `function uploadComplete(evt) {
    var uploadResult = document.getElementById('message');
    uploadResult.innerHTML = evt.target.responseText;
} `

Comment: And you are wondering that it _displays_ the file content – when that is exactly what you are doing in your callback function …? Anyway, you will not get a download dialog for any response to an AJAX request, _because_ AJAX is a background request. You need to either make that request _not_ be a background request (so without AJAX, using a normal `form`), or you need to specifically handle the response you get from your AJAX request, so that the browser will trigger a download dialog (creating a DATA URI from it and assigning it to `location.href`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call any `header` function calls before you output data. Otherwise you will get a headers "Headers already sent" warning, and the headers will not be set.

**Example:**

```
...
// Namming the filename that will be generated.
$name      = 'file_name';
$date      = date("Ymd");
$json_name = $name."-".$date;

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$json_name.'.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Clean the output buffer.
ob_clean();

echo $results;
```

Comment: @user4076077 Then the issue must be somewhere in the omitted portion of your code. Can you add a minimal recreation?

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo "some content to go in a file";

$contentToGoInFile = ob_get_contents(); //this gets the outputted content above and puts it into a varible/buffer
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$json_name.'.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $contentToGoInFile;
exit; //stops execution of code below
```

example with your code

```
$results = $db->loadResult(); 

// Namming the filename that will be generated.
$name      = 'file_name';
$date      = date("Ymd");
$json_name = $name."-".$date;

ob_start();
echo $results;
$contentToGoInFile = ob_get_contents(); //this gets the outputted content above and puts it into a varible/buffer
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$json_name.'.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $contentToGoInFile;
exit
```